# Can I use a different size post for gate than the fence?

Tags: fence, post

If I'm using a 6x6 post to attached a heavy garden gate can I use 4x4 post for the rest of fence?

Comment: Not only can you, it's an excellent idea to use a beefier post for a heavy gate.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Just make sure the face where the fence attaches, is in line with the 4x4s.

[image]